# Spring redirect simple rest POST with body (json) on another port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, controller, port

I have 2 spring rest applications.
When I send data to the first one,

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String productName;
private Double productValue;
```

First I create a client entry in DB with the fields:

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
```

and than
I would like to make a redirect post to another port, another application
handling product data with body including the two fields:

```
private String productName;
private Double productValue;
private Long clientId;
```

to create a product entry in the db
after creating product, I would like to redirect back to the first app and show the saved client.

The question is, how should I build my Controller?
Do I have to use ModelAndView? - this is only a backend rest, without any front (run from postman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to do this way first autowire `RestTemplate` and then use it to call another `api` -

```
@RestController
public class ProductResource {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repository;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Product> saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        Product productSavedAtClient = repository.save(product);
        Product savedProduct = restTemplate.postForObject("http://some.other.app/product", productSavedAtClient, Product.class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(savedProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was missing